# Player gets dislocated on scene restart

Tags: unity-game-engine

My starting player position is (0, 0, 0), when I restart the scene, its starting position gets changed to (0, 0.9, 0). And this doesn't happen on every restart, sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

I want to to mention another fact that is interesting to me, is that I have 2 restart buttons, one on game over (retry button) and one on the pause menu (in the upper corner). Which are calling the same restart function, and only the retry button is causing this bug.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Hod do you restart the scene? Is rigidbody attached to the player?

Comment: @Programmer
`SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);`
And yes I have rigidbody atached on the player.

Comment: I suspect that you have DontDestroyOnload on that object or the collider of the player is already going through another object so the rigidbody tries to separate them. This will be hard to figure out without seeing your complete code or the screenshot of the player collider setup

Comment: @Programmer I kinda found whats the problem, but I am not sure how to solve it.
Player in my game moves upwards in the sky, when it hits enemy object, it falls down on the ground (Changing gravity 0 to 2), the ground has collider to stop him (Then the scene restarts). Looks like the bigger the magnitude, the bigger the dislocation.